# custom authentication decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I'm trying to implement a decorator that authenticates the user's token before granting access to a function. My current implementation is kind of wonky in that I need to do two queries since I can't get locals in the decorator. Is there a better way to do this?

```py
def require_auth(func):
    print 'require_auth'
    @wraps(func)
    def inner():
        if 'token' in request.json:
            token = request.json['token']
            session = Session()
            for instance in session.query(SQLTypes.User).filter(SQLTypes.User.token==token):
                auth_user = instance.username
            try:
                auth_user
                print 'authenticated!'
            except NameError:
                abort(401)
        else:
            abort(401)
        return func()
    return inner

@app.route('/st/projects', methods=['POST'])
@require_auth
def post_project():

    session = Session()

    for instance in session.query(SQLTypes.User).filter(SQLTypes.User.token==request.json['token']):
        auth_user = instance.username

    # do something with auth_user

    session.close()
```

Comment: What version of Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your authenticated user in `flask.g`:

```
from flask import g

# ...

def require_auth(func):

    # ...

    for instance in session.query(SQLTypes.User).filter(SQLTypes.User.token==token):
        g.auth_user = instance.username
    try:
        g.auth_user
        print 'authenticated!'
    except AttributeError:
        abort(401)

    # ...
```

Then in your view function you can access the user as `g.auth_user`.